# How to launch an application as a dock on openbox

Tags: x11, openbox, xdotool, wmctrl

If i do `obxprop|grep dock` and click on `gnome-panel` for example, my result is :

```
_OB_APP_TYPE(UTF8_STRING) = "dock"
```

For the rest, it's :

```
_OB_APP_TYPE(UTF8_STRING) = "normal"
```

How can i force a program to be a "dock". (ignore `<margin>` and such)

I have a bug after an openbox's margin right of 100px. There are a few pixels where i can't go.

```
wmctrl -r "something" -e 0,0,0,-1,-1
```

doesn't go on `0,0` but on something like `0,15`...

Edit : `wmctrl` can send a program labeled as "dock" on `0,0`. (For example set option for `dock` in `gkrellm`)